# gnome-system-monitor error - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have been intermittently getting this error when I try to run gnome-system-monitor in Ubuntu 14.04.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Error:
(gnome-system-monitor:20318): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: g-io-error-quark
code  : 0
what  : Unable to find default local directory monitor type
(gnome-system-monitor:20318): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_present_with_time: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

[sysinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTaC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid that the answer is that there is no answer. It looks to be a known issue: [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1430068). [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bugs?field.tag=utopic) is the utopic page containing the issue. You should mark yourself as being affected by this bug so that it will prompt for priority and ranking from the dev team rather than remaining in the *"undecided"* state.

Comment: Ah...looks like that has been an issue for a while. I will take your suggestion and mark myself as affected. Thanks!